# How to prevent ST2 from searching in excluded folders?

Tags: windows, search, sublime-text-2, exclude

I've got a sublime-project like this:

```
{
   "folders":
   [
      {
         "path": ".",
         "folder_exclude_patterns": ["_doc", "cache", "logs", "_release"],
         "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-workspace"]
      }
   ]
}
```

In particular I'm excluding `_doc`, `_release`, etc. from the project. They seem to be excluded fine since they don't show up in the side bar. However, when I do a search, ST also searches in these folders and returns all kind of unrelated results.

For instance, if I do this search:

[image]

I get results such as this, even though the file is in the _doc folder, which has been excluded:

[image]

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Did you try adding those folders to your User settings instead of just your project settings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try to use `<project>` or `<open folders>` instead of dot (`.`) in **Where:** field.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I've asked everywhere but it seems not many people know this. It changed a lot the way I work with ST2 - now instead of waiting 1 minute for the search to complete and get a bunch of unrelated results, it takes 2 seconds with proper results (using `<project>`). I will award the bounty tomorrow when the system allows me to do so. Thanks again for this!